# How do I use output parameter from Execute SQL Task to fetch additional data using Data Flow Task?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

I have a scenario where I need to fetch data from **`Database 1`** on `Server 1` and insert into **`Database 2`** on `Server 2` on a particular condition.

I am using SSIS 2008.

1. First I fetch an ID from `Database 2` using `Execute SQL Task`.
2. Then, I use the ID from step 1 and fetch a set of rows from `Database 1` again using another `Execute SQL Task`
3. I now want to insert these fetched rows back into `Database 2`.

I guess I should probably use a Foreach Container but I feel that there should be a better way to do the step 2 using a Data Flow Task`.

I know there is a way to pass parameters (**ID**) using  `Execute SQL Task` but I cannot find a way to pass the the output of the `Execute SQL Task` (**ID**) as an input to the data flow task.

Is it possible? Or is there a better way to do what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: @Siva Where does that (extremely long) other answer you linked to, in any way address the question asked here?  Specifically, how does it address the question of "*How to pass a parameter to a Data Flow Task from an Execute SQL Task?*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks RBarryYoung !
Thank You Siva for helping me out! I went through your post and it could be helpful in
something I would be trying out next.

I found the solution I was looking for in the blog below :

and I put step 2 & step 3 within a single Data Flow Task.

http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2009/03/05/mapping-stored-procedure-parameters-in-ssis-ole-db-source-editor.aspx

Thanks!
SA